# UIButton glow effect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, glow

I need some help with UIButtons,

I was wondering how to get the glow effect that I set with the code below to respond to where the touch is.

```
[C setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
```

The idea is that when the button is touched it will follow where the touch is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this yourself. Load a glow png into a `UIImageView` and add it into the view hierarchy. Then set the view's position based on touches.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDlkm.png

Comment: Are you sure there's no other way? that's gonna be a pain in the ass :P

Comment: @mr It cannot be done using the showsTouchWhenHighlighted property, and I do believe making a custom image that follows a gesture would be the best alternative.

Comment: It's easier than you think. Try it. I added a link to a 'glow' image in my answer.

Comment: OK, thanks, By the way, your link is just a white 45*45 pixels square, never mind, I'll figure that out. thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Awesome No, it's not completely white.

Comment: @pt2ph8 Just to inform you, I got the glow to work perfectly :)