# Glow effect to custom UIButton like info UIButton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

As I am new in iphone development. I want to give glow effect like "info UIButton" to  "custom UIButton".

[image] --> [image]

Please help me in this case, to give the above effect on button tap.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8203571/uibutton-glow-effect?rq=1**

      Check This it will help you !!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found an easy way to do as I want.
It's by enabling check mark of "Shows Touch On Highlight" property. 
See the screenshot..

[image]

It's working fine for my custom buttons.

Answer (score 6):

if you do not want to use image then use below code
import 'CoreGraphics framework' to use below code

```
-(IBAction)myButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *tmpbtn=(UIButton *)sender;
 tmpbtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor cyanColor].CGColor;
 tmpbtn.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
 tmpbtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
 tmpbtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
}
```

To remove glow effect just add

```
-(void)removeBtnGlow
{
   myBtn.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
   myBtn.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
   myBtn.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
   myBtn.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cut the image of glow effect like and  use this code

```
[yourBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimagename"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create an image of a glowing version of your button icon and set it in code like this:

```
[yourButton setImage:glowImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

or in the interface builder:

[image: This is the default image for the button]
[image: This would be how you set your glowing icon]

Answer (score 1):

As a `UIBUtton` category and by using `glowWithProgress:` you can animate glow change

```
@implementation UIButton (Extra)

-(void)addGlow{
    [self glowWithProgress:1.0];
}

-(void)removeGlow{
    [self glowWithProgress:0.0];
}

-(void)glowWithProgress:(CGFloat)progress{
    CGFloat realProgress = MAX(.0f, MIN(1.0f, progress));
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f * realProgress;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
}

@end
```